# Loop through spreadsheets in the workbook and copy information into row 4 (starting with column B)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a code that will loop through the sheets in workbook and copy information that is located in cell A7 in every sheet. I also need it to skip the duplication, for example if information in cell A7 is the same in multiple sheets, I need it to be copied only once into cell B4 in "Data Quality" sheet and move to another sheet until until it finds different information and then copy that new information into C4 etc.

Here is the beginning of the code to start the loop:

```
InputData()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        Set DestSh = Sheets("Data Quality")
        For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Select Case sh.Name
                Case DestSh.Name, "Overall Summary", "Confidence Level", "Standard Reporting Rules"
                Case Else
```

Here I need to enter code to copy information from cell A7 on each sheet into row 4 starting with column B and if there are any duplicates to remove them.

Comment: Use a scripting.dictionary to collect the unique cells then after you have processed all the sheets and have a dictionary with a set of unique values write the values to your desired row.

Comment: Freeflow hit the big answer... that is probably the most efficient way.  if you don't go that route, you want an if statement to `match()` your current value and if not found, dynamically find the last column and paste it into the last column + 1...

Answer (score 1):

Will show general for both options from the comment (both untested):

**dictionary:**

```
dim dc as scripting.dictionary, i as long, ws as worksheet
set dc as new scripting.dictionary
for each ws in worksheets
    dc(ws.cells(7,1).value)=ws.cells(7,1).value 
next
sheets("data quality").cells(4,2).resize(,dc.count+2).value = application.transpose(dc.keys)
```

**match():**

```
dim ws as worksheet, lcd as long
for each ws in worksheets
    with sheets("data quality")
        if isempty(.cells(4,2).value) then
            lcd = 2
        else
            lcd = .cells(4,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).columns
        end if
        if not application.match(ws.cells(7,1).value,.range(.cells(4,2),.cells(4,lcd)),0) then .cells(4,lcd+1).value = ws.cells(7,1).value
    end with
next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am getting an error msg for   lcd = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns

Comment: @InnaG what is the error message?  if the row has no data, you would need to build logic for that

Comment: Each cell A7 all the sheets in the file has name of the product in it. I need to copy all the names in the row 4 starting with column B but without duplication, for example if one sheet has "hammer" in cell A7 - I want this to copy in the "Data Quality" sheet, if next sheet has the same product - it needs to be skiped and go to the next sheet and so on. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @InnaG Each example will loop through sheets in the workbook, referring to cell A7, `cells(7,1)`,  For the **dictionary** example, the value is added as a key... only 1 key can exist, so this removes duplicates inherently; once the dictionary is filled is pastes all keys starting at B4 on Data Quality.  For the **match()** example, it verifies that there is no match in the current Data Quality sheet, and if not it appends the value to the last column +1.  Both should do what you are asking, though you may need to build in a little more logic to tailor to your specific needs.

Comment: @InnaG updated code to reflect mitigating no data in cell B2 of Data Quality, in the `Match()` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative answer using `For Each Loop` and  `CounntIf`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Long
c = 2

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Data Quality" Then
            Sheets("Data Quality").Cells(4, c).Value = ws.Cells(7, 1).Value
        c = c + 1
        End If
    Next ws

    With Sheets("Data Quality")
    Dim lCol As Long, cnt As Long
    lCol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For x = lCol To 2 Step -1
        cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(4, x)), Cells(4, x))
            If cnt > 1 Then Cells(4, x).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Next x
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you, but its not working like I need it, I need value of cell A7 from all sheets in workbook to be copied to cell B4 in the "Data Quality" sheet.  This code works, but it also copies other cells, that I do not need . I only need value in A7 without dups.

Comment: @InnaG updated, this code works, I misread your description and was using "C4" as the start cell instead of cell "B4". After all the values are copied to the "Data Quality" worksheet the Duplicates are deleted, providing a range of unique values in row 4 starting at cell "B4"